# Function/Procedure to delete tables by date without deleting system tables

Tags: mysql, sql

As explained in the title above, I'm trying to write an sql function to delete tables by date without deleting the system tables. I've put an image below this message for a visual interpretation of my problem. Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you for your time!
[image]

Comment: You drop tables by name but I am at unclear how you distinguish system tables.

Comment: Maybe it's still too early for me, but I am not even sure what "deleting tables by date" is supposed to mean. How are you determining a table's "date"?

Comment: I'm trying to determine a table by date created .. That's the original idea .. But I'm open to new suggestions / ideas .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of tables by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. It can be filtered by schema and create time.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE CREATE_TIME [criteria]
AND TABLE_SCHEMA [criteria]
;
```

Since you do not seem to be referring to the "mysql" schema when you mention "system" tables, you will probably need to devise a table_name condition for the above query to exclude those tables.

Once you have these results, you can use procedural code to dynamically create queries to DROP those tables. You cannot dynamically drop those tables with one query... but this query can be modified to generate the queries for you:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '`;') AS dropQuery
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

I work on this solution:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Delete_Tables`()
BEGIN
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @tables = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('`', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`') INTO @tables FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'testschema' AND CREATE_TIME > '19/05/2019';

CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(@tables) THEN 
        SELECT 'NULL VALUE DETECTED' AS Verification;
    ELSE 
        SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
        select @tables;
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tables;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
END CASE;
END

Thanks for the help!